# Get the href values that have a checkbox checked?

Tags: javascript, html, xul

let say i have something similar to this :

```
<input class="checkbox_google" type="checkbox"><a href="http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_avril" onmousedown="return"><em>10</em> avril - Wikipédia</a>
<input class="checkbox_google" type="checkbox"><a href="http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_avril" onmousedown="return"><em>10</em> avril - Wikipédia</a>
<input class="checkbox_google" type="checkbox"><a href="http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_avril" onmousedown="return"><em>10</em> avril - Wikipédia</a>
```

I would like to get the href value of the  that have a checkbox checked before, if it is possible.

Edit : I am developing a mozilla extension, and what the extension should do is add a checkbox before each link generated by a google search, till now it is good, but what i need now is get the links that have the checkbox checked. Sorry for the confusion

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wuh? I'm so confused.

Comment: Do we have to decode the question for you .. Unless you make your question clear no one can be of help to you

Comment: ok sorry i try to explain better
ps : thank you adeneo for editing ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox_google');
    hrefs = [];

for (var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].checked) 
        hrefs.push( boxes[i].nextSibling.href );
}

console.log(hrefs.join(', ')); // now has the href valus of the checked boxes
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zjsnc/)

Comment: Thanks a lot adeneo again      
That is exactly what i need     
and thanks a lot for being so quick

Comment: This works by selecting the next sibling, and be aware that a linebreak or just a space between the input and the anchor will be registered as a textNode, and be picked up by nextSibling, so for that to work, the code must be like in the question, where there is no space between the input and the following anchor element.